# Get file or all folder from SFTP without save it localy

Tags: java, ftp, sftp

I have functionality (Java 8 app) to read files from FTP by Apache Commons

```
 FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
        ftp.connect(
                FtpProperties.getHost(), 
                FtpProperties.getPort()
        );
        boolean login = ftp.login(
                FtpProperties.getUname(), 
                FtpProperties.getPass()
        );
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/files");
        FTPFile[] files = ftp.listFiles();
```

Files are not explicitly saved locally anywhere. I download to the `files[]` by `ftp.listFiles()`. In my files[] i have of all files from ftp directtory.  And I can display them normally, save them, do whatever I want with them.

Does anyone know of an analogous solution for SFTP ?

**SOLUTION:**

```
public static void ls() throws Exception {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession("user", "host", port);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setPassword("password");
        session.connect();

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

        Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> returnVector = sftpChannel.ls("/files");
        List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry item : returnVector) {
            returnList.add(item.getFilename());
        }
        System.out.println(returnList);
    }
```

`System.out.println(returnList);` result in console:

```
[myfile.txt]
```

This is it what i wanted to achieve. Thanks Rob !

Comment: Try http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Comment: In JSCH, every solution I found involved explicitly declaring where the file should be saved locally.

Comment: You understand that `ftp.listFiles()` doesn't download anything, it just returns informational objects. It's similar to `channelSftp.ls` from JSch. That returns a non-generic (ugh) `Vector` (double ugh), but the `ChannelSftp.LsEntry` objects are similar to `FTPFile`.

Comment: i can't see .lsEntry method in ChanelSftp

Comment: The method is called `ls`: https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.LsEntry.html. It's also overloaded if you prefer that: `https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#ls-java.lang.String-com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.LsEntrySelector-`

Comment: thanks ;) i have solution. I will make them available here